# Writing to csv/excel based on header in Java

Tags: java, json, excel, file, csv

I have a JSON which has entries that look like

> [{    "key": {        "keyLabel": "Label1"    },  "specs": [{         "specKey":
>   "spec1",      "specValue": ["s11"]    }, {        "specKey": "spec2",
>         "specValue": ["s12"]    }] },
>
> {  "key": {        "keyLabel":
>   "Label2"  },  "specs": [{         "specKey": "spec1",         "specValue":
>   ["s21"]   }, {        "specKey": "spec3",         "specValue":
>   ["s22"]   }] }]

Spec Keys present changes on the basis of KeyLabel value. As you can see above if if KeyLabel = Label1, spec1 and spec2 are present. If KeyLabel = Label2, spec1 and spec3 are present

I want to create a CSV/Excel using this such that header/top row as following columns

> KeyLabel, spec1, spec2, spec3 (basically union of all specKeys)
>
> Label1,      s11,s12
>
> Label2, s21, ,s22

So, the challenging part is that at the time of writing to file, I need to write under in the appropriate column.

Any thoughts on if there are any csv/excel libraries which make this easier. Naive way does seem very elegant - which is to store the ordered list of headers and basic on key write commas and values so that values are in write column

Comment: I guess for your expected output on Label2 should be: `Label2, s21, ,s22`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need specific library for doing that.
You should only need some common library `jackson` `poi-ooxml`

1. First, you should read json string to POJO object (ref: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

   List examples = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference>() {});
2. Seconds, collect header

   List header = examples
           .stream()
           .map(Example::getSpecs)
           .flatMap(Collection::stream)
           .map(Spec::getSpecKey)
           .distinct()
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   header.add(0, "Key");
3. Next, use POI library write excel file

final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName("sheetname"));

```
    // Headers
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    for (int index = 0; index < headers.size(); index++) {
        row.createCell(index).setCellValue(headers.get(index));
    }

    // Content
    int startRow = 1;
    for (Example object : objects) {
        row = sheet.createRow(startRow++);
        // key label

        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(object.getKey().getKeyLabel());
        // spec
        for (int index = 1; index < headers.size(); index++) {
            String speckey = headers.get(index);
            String value = object.getSpecs().stream().filter(e -> e.getSpecKey().equals(speckey)).findAny().map(Spec::getSpecValue).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).toString();
            row.createCell(index).setCellValue(value);
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\poi-generated-file.xlsx");
    try {
        workbook.write(fileOut);
    } finally {
        fileOut.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
```

It only example code. You should modify and update to better.